# How do I detect the signal and ground wire on a bluetooth earphone cable?

Tags: soldering, wireless, bluetooth

I have a wireless bluetooth earphone, on which the left driver plays at half volume. I want to cut off the drivers and solder in a mmcx connector so that I can have options on the drivers. However assuming the color coding isn't standard or nonexistent, how do I detect the ground and signal wires without an option of doing a continuity test against 3.5mm jack ?

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a ground if the drivers operate fully bridged (wikipedia: [h-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge)).

A shorted transistor on a h-bridge leg would also nicely explain a half volume output level.

Comment: so how to ensure the new connection won't make drivers play out of phase ? The electronics and battery are pretty well sealed, and me clumsily cracking them open might compromise the sweatproofing.